# How to make a figure a subplot of another figure in matplotlib 2.0.2?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a function that creates a figure object called `fig1` which is of type `<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>`:

```
 def plotter1():
     fig = Figure(figsize = (15, 7))
     ....
     return fig1
```

Now, I would like to use the output of the above function and embed it into another figure object called `fig`:

```
def plotter2():
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=False, figsize = (15, 4))
    plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
    ...
    plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
    ...
    plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
    # here I would like to put the fig1 as the third subplot of fig object.

    return fig
```

Note: I want to minimize the changes I make to `plotter1()` and `plotter2()` as much as possible.

I have tried many solutions available on stackoverflow, and none seem to work as I am not certain I understand the changes in matplotlib over time and whether this task is doable in matplotlib 2.0.2 (which I am stuck with and I have no permission to use any other version).

Comment: No this is not possible in Matplotlib.  `plotter1` and `plotter2` would be better written to take the figure as an optional argument, and then with more modern Matplotlib you could use subfigure.  However, 2.0.2 is quite old, so it does not have subfigure